# Can an estimate of total production be made from a random set of serial numbers

Tags: distributions

I hope this makes sense.

I have a series of 163 serial numbers that fall between 77.681.001 to 78.786.366.

The item that these numbers have been assigned to have all now been produced and sold, but the total amount in circulation is not known. it is estimated the number could be 1,000 to 5,000 based on past and similar production runs.

My question is, can a statistical process be applied to find an estimate of how many items were produced from these 163 known serial numbers within the known range?

I have heard of the German Tank problem is that something I could look at?

Appreciate some idea if an estimation can be ascertained through statistical methodology.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand. There are a total of 163 distinct products that have been produced and all you know is that the frequency for each one of these is at least one. You now want to estimate the total frequency based on this fact, and the fact that in the past there were roughly from 1000 to 5000 total (in a given unit of time)?

Comment: I have a total number of known serials out of an unknown amount of  x produced - I would like to get an estimate as to what number x might be.

Comment: How did you find out you have 163 products in circulation? Was this a sort of sample? Do you also have frequencies for each of these 163 products?

Comment: I asked those who had purchased a product (through an online group) to send me their serial numbers. So only those in the group will have sent these to me. So there will be x amount out there in total. No idea on frequency at all. All I have are 163 confirmed serial numbers but know many more were produced - being x  and all produced over a two year period. The item is a Limited Edition watch production.

Comment: If you selected your subjects based on some criteria, for ex. only those that are part of an online group, or if only some people of those whom you sent a query responded, then you have a non-representative and possibly biased sample of the population. So any analysis will be dubious.

Comment: Nevertheless, how many people did you ask for their serial number? How many responded? Did some people give you the same serial number? Do some serial numbers in your sample have frequency higher than 1?

Comment: The items have now all been produced and sold, but the total amount in circulation (x) is not known. I only know of 163 and it is estimated the number could be between 1,000 to 5,000 based on past and similar production runs by the same company.

My question is what statistical process can be applied to find an estimate of x, that is, can I get an estimate of just how many items could have been produced by only knowing these 163 known serial numbers?

Comment: Maybe, if you had frequencies rather than just unique numbers. Otherwise I do not know of a way to solve this. Have you checked the wikipedia page for the german tank problem? It has some pretty straight forward formulas for estimating what you seem to be interested in.